# onPause and persisting custom class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, persistence, android-lifecycle

I have an `Activity` with the goals to edit some custom class `A`. I use a `Fragment`, which is passed an instance of `a` in it's static creation method `Fragment newInstance(A foo)`. This instance is then parcelled (`Parcelable` interface implemented on `A`) into the fragment arguments. This means that my `Activity` does not share the same object instance with the `Fragment`.

The user can edit some properties of `A` using `View`s available with the `Fragment`. At the 'on pause' lifecycle event, I want to sync the `View` fields to my instance of `A`. The view-state is already properly persisted, so I don't have to worry about that.

How should I implement this further? I'm thinking of persisting my data objects in a MySQLite database. Should my `Activity` by responsible for updating the updated instance of `A`? Or should my `Fragment` perform this job?

Answer (score 0):

There is something you can check out like ormLite and GreenDAO.  They do data persistence and wraps sqlLite db's.  GreenDAO is what i've used in the past to do things like this.

http://greendao-orm.com/

Comment: While indeed useful to take a look at, this does not answer my question on which class is supposed to be responsible for causing the persistence to happen in the first place. Maybe you can comment on that as well?

Comment: Ahh I misread your question, my apologies.  I would suggest using the fragment to make a call to persist the data.  My reasoning is that if you ever need to reuse this in another activity you can do that, vs having to duplicate code at the activity level.